# For loop vectorization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there a way I could vectorize this for loop and make it faster in MATLAB for large n?

```
for j=1:n
  % find point coordinate in a different basis
  pt_2(:,:,j) = Mat(:,:,t(j)) * pt_1(:,:,j);
end
```

where `pt_1`, `pt_2` are `3x1xn` arrays, `Mat` is a `3x3xm` array, and `t` is a `nx1` vector. The loop wants to get n point coordinates transformed from n coordinates of another linear space, and there are m different transformations.

Comment: Can you provide example of the inputs, so that we can execute this code. Its difficult to check it if you cant run the code.

Comment: The values come from some prior calculations but maybe you could use some arbitrary values: e.g. n=200000; m=20; pt_1=ones(3,1,n); Mat=ones(3,3,m); pt_2=zeros(3,1,n); It's just for testing the loop execution time.

Comment: Thanks. But t is still missing.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe t=ones(n,1). Sounds silly but as long as it is accessing values every time. t is a mapping from [1,n] to [1,m], it decides which of the m categories does each number from 1 to n belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent form is to take `pt_1(:,:,j)` ,transpose it and repeat it 3 times and form a 3 * 3 matrix so we have:

```
pt_1_j = [pt_1(:,:,j).' ; pt_1(:,:,j).' ; pt_1(:,:,j).'];
```

then we can multiply `Mat(:,:,t(j))` by `pt_1_j` elementwise

```
M = Mat(:,:,t(j)) .* pt_1_j;
```

then sum `M` along its 2nd dimension

```
pt_2(:,:,j) = sum(M,2);
```

also the same thing can be done with `bsxfun`

```
M = bsxfun(@times , Mat(:,:,t(j)) , pt_1(:,:,j).');
pt_2(:,:,j) = sum(M,2)
```

or

```
pt_2(:,:,j) = sum(bsxfun(@times , Mat(:,:,t(j)) , pt_1(:,:,j).'),2)
```

Generalizing the above method to 3 dimensions:

`Mat` is precomputed for all iterations so `Mat(:,:,t)` is use instead of `M(:,:,t(j))` and `permute` is used for transpose of 3D data.

then apply `sum(bsxfun...`

```
pt_2 = sum(bsxfun(@times, Mat(:,:,t), permute(pt_1,[2 1 3])), 2);
```